# permission errors when trying to install dcapulse

Tags: permissions

I am getting `permission denied` while trying to install software

```
novacopy@novacopy-VirtualBox:~$ wget https://install.printfleetcdn.com/dca-pulse/1.1.0.3955/SbXXUm8m5pjMoGwxljF1UPcK2Y/Linux-x86_64/dcapulse-1.1.0.3955-Linux-x86_64-install-[P3RQE1JEXFS8].sh
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2017-09-05 14:52:27--  https://install.printfleetcdn.com/dca-pulse/1.1.0.3955/SbXXUm8m5pjMoGwxljF1UPcK2Y/Linux-x86_64/dcapulse-1.1.0.3955-Linux-x86_64-install-[P3RQE1JEXFS8].sh
Resolving install.printfleetcdn.com (install.printfleetcdn.com)... 54.227.199.89
Connecting to install.printfleetcdn.com (install.printfleetcdn.com)|54.227.199.89|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3240330 (3.1M) [application/octet-string]
Saving to: ‘dcapulse-1.1.0.3955-Linux-x86_64-install-[P3RQE1JEXFS8].sh.5’

dcapulse-1.1.0.3955-Linux-x86_64-in 100%[=================================================================>]   3.09M   526KB/s    in 5.5s    

2017-09-05 14:52:34 (572 KB/s) - ‘dcapulse-1.1.0.3955-Linux-x86_64-install-[P3RQE1JEXFS8].sh.5’ saved [3240330/3240330]

$ chmod +x dcapulse-1.1.0.3955-Linux-x86_64-install-[P3RQE1JEXFS8].sh
$ ./dcapulse-1.1.0.3955-Linux-x86_64-install-[P3RQE1JEXFS8].sh

PrintFleet DCA Pulse 1.1.0.3955 Installer

Run with --help to see additional options.

 * Installation directory:       /home/novacopy/.dca-pulse
 * Config file path:             /home/novacopy/.dca-pulse/dcapulse.config
 * Running as:                   novacopy
 * Existing version detected:    No
 * Mono 4.4+ detected:           Yes (version 5.2.0.215)

Proceed with install? [yes or no]: yes
Invalid input
Proceed with install? [yes or no]: y
Checking config file..
touch: cannot touch '/home/novacopy/.dca-pulse/dcapulse.config': Permission denied
[sudo] password for novacopy: 
Changing ownership of /home/novacopy/.dca-pulse/dcapulse.config to novacopy..
chown: changing ownership of '/home/novacopy/.dca-pulse/dcapulse.config': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Try running your commands with 'sudo' at the beginning for administrator privileges.

Comment: Add the output of `namei -lx /home/novacopy/.dca-pulse/dcapulse.config`, please.